# IBM AppScan Why does the "Application Error" still appeared where implementation already done?

Tags: error-handling

I am using the IBM app scan and we have found this error shown as "Informational" rather than severity = High. We have implemented codes to countermeasure it but after the second round scan it still there. May I know what is the purpose of all these informational scan results?
[image: Error msg]

Answer (score 0):

AppScan is telling you it was able to trigger an application error in your app. Most likely your application isn't correctly checking the value that AppScan put into this parameter. This isn't necessarily a security vulnerability, which is why it is listed as informational. Informational issues are there for you to review and potentially take action.

If you click the issue, you can see more details about it in the 'Issue Details' pane. The information there includes an advisory, that explains the nature of the problem. It also shows the full HTTP request and response, including the parameter or cookie value that AppScan modified in order to trigger the issue. You should review that information to see why your fix  has apparently not solved the problem.